# Why is my val_loss going down but my val_accuracy stagnates

Tags: python, keras

So I train my model with a dataset and for each epoch I can see the `loss` and `val_loss` go down (it is important to note that `val_loss` will go down to a certain point, but then it stagnates as well, having some minor ups and downs) and `accuracy` go up but for some reason my `val_accuracy` stays at roughly 0.33.
I browsed this and it seems to be a problem of overfitting so i added `Dropout` layers and regularization by using `l2` on some layers of the model but it seems to have no effect. Therefore I would like to ask you what do you think I could improve in my model in order to make the `val_loss` keep going down and my `val_accuracy` not stagnate and therefore keep going up.

I've tried to use more images but the problem seems to be the same.. Not sure if my increment of images was enough tho.

Should I add `Dropout` layers in the `Conv2D` layers?
Should I use less or more `l2` regularization?
Should I use even more images?
Just some questions that might have something to do with my problem.

My model is below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(580, 360, 1), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.05)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.05)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.02)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.02)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.05)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Flatten())  # Flattening the 2D arrays for fully connected layers

model.add(Dense(532, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(266, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Reshape((7, 38)))

print(model.summary())
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.00001)
model.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: Here is the graph of training:

[image]

PS2: Here is the end of training:

```
209/209 [==============================] - 68s 327ms/step - loss: 0.7421 - accuracy: 0.9160 - val_loss: 3.8159 - val_accuracy: 0.3152
Epoch 40/40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a classic overfitting problem.

It would be nice to have a more detailed introduction to the problem, like is it a classification task? Are your images grayscale? What is the purpose of this network?

With this information I would say that any proper regularization to the network should help. Some item you could try:

- For conv layers I recommend using [SpatialDropout layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/SpatialDropout2D).
- Get more data (if possible)
- Use data augmentation (if possible)
- Increase the rate of the dropout layers
- Try reducing the complexity of your model architecture (maybe fewer layers, fewer number of filters in general, fewer number of neurons in dense layers, etc.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am sorry for not providing all the necessary information so to complete, here it comes. It is a classification task in which I try to use a model to recognise license car plates. All my images are indeed grayscale. With that being said i will for sure try to do what you suggested since inverting the order of number of filters as was earlier suggested did not fix the problem although I got slightly better results with it. Thanks!

Comment: @BlueRoss Great! Tell me how it goes please. And kindly complete the answer with those details so more people may try to help you.

Comment: Hey, so turns out i just needed to use more data in order to achieve my goal, like a better train/validation percentage. I also added some more regularization as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint :

You have a problem with your CNN architecture, the size must be lower and lower at each convolution, but in your case it is growing: you have 16, 32, 64, 64, 128. You should do that in the reverse manner. Start from input_shape=(580,360) and then you may go, let us say to shapes 256, 128, 64, 32 for Conv2D.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll try this and let you know how it went! Thanks again.

Comment: I don't share this thought. In general, first layers use to detect low level, basic features of the images, while deeper layers use to detect more complex features of the image. Thus, it is a common practice to have more filters for the latter than for the first layers. Just take a look at almost any architecture, like [VGG16](https://towardsdatascience.com/step-by-step-vgg16-implementation-in-keras-for-beginners-a833c686ae6c) for example.

Comment: Hmm interesting, so in your opinion, what could I improve in my model? Thanks!

Comment: @alan.elkin : In VGG16 you have shapes with larger depth and lower length/width, it is what I was saying in fact. I suppose I have been misunderstood.

Comment: For Conv2D, choose chapes for ex : 256, then 128, 64 etc. Chack also the link in the reposne of alan.